# how to switch between compilers when the server is written in python and client in cpp?

Tags: visual-studio

[image]I am currently using Visual Studio IDE ,I worked with VS Code and using diffrent coding languges is very easy using the VS code. How ever in my current project I need to work with the Visual Studio IDE . My problem is that in my project the code for the server is written in Python and the code for client is written in CPP. For some reason I cant manage to run the CPP file , only the PYTHON file . In other words if I press Start and currently the tab is in the client code (that is written in Cpp) , the PYTHON code is compiled and **not** the CPP code , how do I change the compilers?

I tried watching sevrel videos on youtube such as that :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_a3b8fCznQI

but it did not help .

I add picture of the files that are currently in the same folder :

I added 2 pictures.
the first one is showing the start button that I press
[image: be4_pressing_start_button]
the second picture is shwoing what happned after I press the start button.as you can see insted of runng the cpp file it runs the python file.
[image: after_pressing_start_button]

edit:
I added this pic to show that now I have to python files in my Server_python project.
the first is : Server_python.
py the second is: AES_key.py .
when I press Project and then press Set as Sturtup Project I run the the server_python.py code and not the AES_key code . how to make the VS run the AES_key using the "set As sturtup Project" ?

[image: having to python files,but only one of them is running]

Comment: Are you sure you set the startup project to the one you want to debug? The "start" button does not care about what file you have open

Comment: Well, the screenshot shows that you have set the Python project as startup project. You need to right click on "Client_cpp" project in the Solution explorer and select "Set as startup project"

Comment: thank you It worked , now is there a shortcut for action: "Set as startup project" ?

Comment: You can click the "Project" Menu and select "Set as Startup project" from there. And set up a keyboard shortcut for that in the options if you need to do this more often

Comment: I tried what you said and did it work ,but now I have to python files .
the first is : Server_python.py
the second is: AES_key.py  . 
when I press Project and then press Set as Sturtup Project . the compiler compiles the Server_python,py code and not the AES_key.py code. Can I run the AES_key.py with out pressing the right click mouse and pressing : "start with out debbuging " in right side of the screen called Solution Explorer ?